# Unusual Gap in HTML horizontal scrollbar

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, gaps-in-visuals

OK, i have a DIV with to scroll bars that are both required, and this is the simple layout I started with:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Testing</title>
</head>

<style>
.Test {
    overflow-x: scroll !important;
    overflow-y: scroll !important;
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
}
</style>

<body>
    <div class="Test"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

When this is displayed in IE9, I get a gap on the right hand size of the horizontal scrollbar.  I have attached an image to show the problem.

[image: An example of what is shown]
Any help as to what is causing this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can replace the `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` with just `overflow: scroll;`. Is `!important` really necessary here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try styling the scroll bar within your div

```
scrollbar-track-color: #cacaca;
```

This made my scroll bar a uniform color.

[Here's where I found it along with some other styling tricks](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/1207-div-scrollbars-color/)